# Printing a certain amount of lines from a file each time the user presses enter in C++

Tags: c++, file, output, line

The following function is supposed to read and print five lines from a file and than prompt the user for five lines more or to quit:

```
void Reader::readNotes() {
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::ifstream file("note.txt");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file: note.txt" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    const int linesPerPage = 5;
    int linesPrinted = 0;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
        ++linesPrinted;
        if (linesPrinted >= linesPerPage) {
            std::string input;
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Press Enter for more, or type 'q' to quit: " << std::endl;
            std::getline(std::cin, input);
            if (input == "q") {
                break; // Exit loop if user types 'q'
            }
            linesPrinted = 0; // Reset lines printed for next page
        }
    }

    file.close();
}
```

The problem is that, at the very first print, ten lines are being printed instead of five.

The output I'm getting  from the first print is:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5

Press Enter for more, or type 'q' to quit:
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10

Press Enter for more, or type 'q' to quit:
```

The intended output is:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5

Press Enter for more, or type 'q' to quit:
```

All the other prints after that, if the user presses enter, print five lines as expected. The only print that goes wrong is the first.

Comment: Try moving printing line and incrementing `linesPrinted` after `if`.

Comment: please post a [mcve] and dont spam tags

Comment: my guess is that tehre is a `std::cin` in the code you didnt show and its this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: With debugging by eye, I couldn't find any issue in your exposed code. Are you sure that there isn't a straying newline in input buffer from something else you called before in the non-exposed code? (Hence, a [mcve] makes sense to dissect the actual source of issue.) ;-)

Comment: tip: if you pass an `istream&` to the funciton and read input from there you can use a `std::stringstream` with hardcoded input for testing. This will make your testing much easier and you could post a [mcve] for us to see. Though even without the file contents you could include the `main` and the rest of the code that is necessary to get it to compile

Comment: Calling only the shown code from `main()` works without errors for me.

Comment: As just mentioned above, this code as shown works and only prints 5 lines at a time. Perhaps when you're running it you're pressing a key other than "q" which will be treated as "Enter". But that's only speculation